# JS Validation - Multiple Loops

Tags: javascript, validation

The following validation is returning an error "missing; before statement".  I have multiple fields on my form that I'm trying to validate.  One field drives which fields need to be validated.  This field is a radio button containing 1 through 6.  If 6 is selected then (in my code) tdchars would be 123456, if 5 is selected tdchars would be 12345 and so on.  The variable i would be used to append each of those numbers on the end of the field name to reference the correct field to validate.

I am not sure I've created the for loop correctly. If I take the loop out, it saves fine.  I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you in advance.

```js
`function getRadioButtonValue(checkboxname) {  
 var x = checkboxname.length; 
 for (var i=0; i < x; i++) {  
  if (checkboxname[i].checked == true) {  
   return checkboxname[i].value; 
  } 
 } 
 return ""; 
}

//THE CODE BELOW IS USED FOR VALIDATION BEFORE SUBMITTING
function validate() {
errMSG = ""
var f = document.forms[0];
var td = getRadioButtonValue(document.forms[0].RAField);

for (td = 1; td <= 6; td++) {
 If (td = 6) {
 var tdChars ="123456";
 }else if (td = 5) {
 var tdChars = "12345";
 }else if (td = 4) {
 var tdChars = "1234";
 }else if (td = 3) {
 var tdChars = "123";
 }else if (td = 2) {
 var tdChars = "12";
 }else {
 var tdChars = "1";
}
 for (i=0; i <=  tdChars.length; i++) {

if(f.JobGuaranteeDuration.selectedIndex<1){
if (errMSG!="") {
   errMSG += "Select a Guarantee Duration for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }else {
   errMSG+="Please correct the following:\n\nSelect a Guarantee Duration for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }
 } 
if(f.JobName.value == '') {
if (errMSG!="") {
   errMSG += "Enter the Project Name for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }else {
   errMSG+="Please correct the following:\n\nEnter the Project Name for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }
 } 
if(f.JobSiteAddress.value =='') {
if (errMSG!="") {
   errMSG += "Enter the Job Site Address for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }else {
   errMSG+="Please correct the following:\n\nEnter the Job Site Address for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }
 } 
if(f.JobSiteCity.value =='') {
if (errMSG!="") {
   errMSG += "Enter the Job Site City for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }else {
   errMSG+="Please correct the following:\n\nEnter the Job Site City for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }
 } 
if(f.JobSiteState.value == '') {
if (errMSG!="") {
   errMSG += "Enter the Job Site State for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }else {
   errMSG+="Please correct the following:\n\nEnter the Job Site State for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }
 } 
if(f.JobSiteZip.value =='') {
if (errMSG!="") {
   errMSG += "Enter the Job Site Zip for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }else {
   errMSG+="Please correct the following:\n\nEnter the Job Site Zip for Roof Contruction(i)\n";
  }
 } 
if (errMSG != "") {
alert(errMSG);
f.SaveOptions.value = '0';
return false
}
f.SaveOptions.value = '1';
return true
}
}`
```

Comment: Your IF statements are invalid, but that isn't causing your error. You need == not =. Single equal sign set value, Double equal signs checks value.

Comment: the First `If` definitely is causing an error.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a semicolon after the statement `errMSG = ""` right at the beginning of the `validate()`function.

For background, see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in a previous answer, the first `if` was causing an error.

That said, here a simpler for loop to get the same string that you want:

```
tdChars = ""
for(i = 1; i< td + 1; i++){
tdChars = tdChars + i.toString()
}
```

Comment: Would this go in the place of the bottom for loop?

Comment: @lisajv3 yes it would go in place of `for (td = 1; td <= 6; td++) {`